# Writing Rust-y code: Keeping references to different structs depending on type of object in XML

Tags: rust

I'm having a hard time formulating this in a rust-y manner, since my brain is still hardwired in Python. So I have a XML file:

```
<xml>
<car>
  <name>First car</name>
  <brand>Volvo</brand>
</car>
<plane>
  <name>First plane</name>
  <brand>Boeing</brand>
</plane>
<car>
  <name>Second car</name>
  <brand>Volvo</brand>
</car>
</xml>
```

In reality it's much more complex and the XML is about 500-1000MB large. I'm reading this using quick-xml which gives me events such as Start (tag start), Text and End (tag end) and I'm doing a state machine to keep track.

Now I want to off-load the parsing of car and plane to different modules (they need to be handled differently) but share a base-implementation/trait.

So far so good.

Now using my state machine I know when I need to offload to the car or the plane:

1. When I enter the main car tag I want to create a new instance of car
2. After that, offload everything until the corresponding `</car>` to it
3. When we reach the end I'm going to call `.save()` on the car implementation to store it elsewhere, and can free/destroy the instance.

But this means in my main loop I need to create a new instance of the car and keep track of it (and the same for plane if that's the main element.

```
    let mut current_xml_section: I_DONT_KNOW_THE_TYPE = Some()
    

    loop {
        match reader.read_event(&mut buf) {

            Ok(Event::Start(ref e)) => {
                if state == State::Unknown {
                    match e.name() {
                        b"car" => {
                            state = State::InSection;
                            current_section = CurrentSection::Car;
                            state_at_depth = depth;
                            
                            current_xml_section = CurrentSection::Car::new(e); // this won't work

                        },
                        b"plane" => {
                            state = State::InSection;
                            current_section = CurrentSection::Plane;
                            state_at_depth = depth;
                            
                            current_xml_section = CurrentSection::Plane::new(e); // this won't work
                        },
                        _ => (),
                    };
                }else{
                    current_xml_section.start_tag(e); // this won't work
                }
                depth += 1;
            },
            Ok(Event::End(ref e)) => {
                depth -= 1;
                if state == State::InSection && state_at_depth == depth {
                    state = State::Unknown;
                    current_section = CurrentSection::Unknown;
                    state_at_depth = 0;
                    
                    current_xml_section.save(); // this won't work
                    // Free current_xml_section here
                }else{
                    if state == State::InSection {
                        current_xml_section.end_tag(e) // this won't work
                    }
                }
            },
            // unescape and decode the text event using the reader encoding
            Ok(Event::Text(e)) => (
                if state == State::InSection {
                    current_xml_section.text_data(e) // this won't work
                }
            ),
            Ok(Event::Eof) => break, // exits the loop when reaching end of file
            Err(e) => panic!("Error at position {}: {:?}", reader.buffer_position(), e),
            _ => (), // There are several other `Event`s we do not consider here
        }

        // if we don't keep a borrow elsewhere, we can clear the buffer to keep memory usage low
        buf.clear();
    }
}
```

So I basically don't know how to keep a reference in the main loop to the "current" object (I'm sorry, Python term), given that:

1. We may or may not have a current tag we're processing
2. That section might be a reference to either Car or Plane

I've also considered:

1. Use Serde, but it's a massive document and frankly I don't know the entire structure of it (I'm black box decoding it) so it would need to be passed to Serde in chunks (and I didn't manage to do that, even though I tried)
2. Keeping a reference to the latest plane, the latest car (and start by creating blank objects outside of the main loop) but it feels ugly
3. Using Generics

Any nudge in the right direction would be welcome as I try to un-Python my brain!

Comment: Two options worth considering depending on how you want to consume it: an enum with a variant for each of plane and car. Or a box containing a trait object to a common trait.

Comment: An enum I'd probably the simplest option.

Comment: I don't understand the issue you are having. You seem to already have a `CurrentSection` enum whose variants you assign to `current_xml_section`. What's wrong with the type of `current_xml_section` being `CurrentSection` or `Option<CurrentSection>`? In the former case you'd initialize it to `CurrentSection::unknown`, and in the latter case to `None` (`Some()` isn't valid and doesn't really make sense).

Comment: @user4815162342 That part works well, the problem is holding a reference to my "New Car" that is continuously fed the sub-tags of the car

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Event driven parsing of XML lends itself particularly well to a scope driven approach, where each level is parsed by a different function.

For example, your main loop could look like this:

```rust
    loop {
        match reader.read_event(&mut buf) {
            Ok(Event::Start(ref e)) => {
                match e.name() {
                    b"car" => handle_car(&mut reader, &mut buf)?,
                    b"plane" => handle_plane(&mut reader, &mut buf)?,
                    _ => return Err("Unexpected Tag"),
                }
            },
            Ok(Event::Eof) => break,
            _ => (),
        }
    }
```

Note that the inner match statement only has to consider the XML tags that can occur at the top level; any other tag is unexpected and should generate an error.

`handle_car` would look something like this:

```rust
fn handle_car(reader: &mut Reader<&[u8]>, buf:&mut Vec<u8>) -> Result<(),ErrType> {

    let mut car = Car::new();

    loop {
        match reader.read_event(buf) {
            Ok(Event::Start(ref e)) => {
                match e.name() {
                    b"name" =>  { 
                        car.name = handle_name(reader, buf)?;
                    },
                    b"brand" =>  {
                        car.brand = handle_brand(reader, buf)?;
                    },
                    _ => return Err("bad tag"),
                }
            },
            Ok(Event::End(ref e)) => break,
            Ok(Event::Eof) => return Err("Unexpected EOF"),
            _ => (),
        }
    }

    car.save();

    Ok(())
}
```

`handle_car` creates its own instance of `Car`, which lives within the scope of that function. It has its own loop where it handles all the tags that can occur within it. If those tags contain yet more tags, you just introduce a new set of handling functions for them. The function returns a `Result` so that if the input structure does not match expectations the error can be passed up (as can any errors produced by quick_xml, which I have ignored but real code would handle).

This pattern has some advantages when parsing XML:

- The structure of the code matches the expected structure of the XML, making it easier to read and understand.
- The state is implicit in the structure of the code. No need for state variables or depth counters.
- Common tags, that appear in multiple places (such as `<name>` and `<brand>` can be handled by common functions that are re-used
- If the XML format you are parsing has nested structures (eg. if `<car>` could contain another `<car>`) this is handled by recursion.
- Your original problem of not knowing how to store the `Car` / `Plane` within the main loop is completely avoided.